# Vue v-if doesn't refresh when value is changed

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I created a formular where the user can fill out one to infinite Forumlars, for this i made a state were the formular data is stored as an array of objects. One forumluar is a object and when the user creates a new Formular a new object is pushed in the array.

Each Formular beginns with one field which after filled out gets checked if it already exists if not it should open up the other field underneath it.

```
<template v-if="$store.state.Zell_Open[$store.state.PAGENUMBER]===true">
```

The Checked state is a array of booleans for each Formular one Bool.
If the Users Checks the state gets Updated correctly and the Zell_Open state is turned to true

[Heres my whole state after checking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u65aj.png)

The Problem is that rest of the formular that should be shown after checking and putting the Zell_Open state on true isnt shown.
If i change the PAGENUMBER state manually (with vue dev tools) one up and down then its shown correctly.

Before i added the [$store.state.PAGENUMBER] part and when the Zell_Open state wasnt a array but instead a single bool (at first it should be just one formular not one to infinite) it worked perfectly fine.

Also i should mention that its always just one Formula shown the one that has the array place of Pagenumber.

Answer (score 0):

use v-show instead of v-if if you mean toogling

1. 

or sometimes vue templates will not accept condition inside of it

2. 

Comment: i tried it with v-show but still the same problem.
The condition is met but the box that should be shown when the condition is met isnt shown. When i manually change a the Pagenumber state one up and down again it is shwon correctly. it feels like it doesnt update before the Page number isnt changed.